# Indenting First Paragraph in a List

Tags: indentation, enumerate, itemize, enumitem

I have an `enumerate` environment and each item contains several paragraphs. Normally, none of the paragraphs are indented, but using the `enumitem` package, I can set the `listparindent` to make all but the first paragraph indented. Neither using the `indentfirst` package nor using `\indent` before the first paragraph indents it. How can I also indent the first paragraph in each item?

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{indentfirst}


    \begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[listparindent=\parindent,parsep=0pt]
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum 
eu ligula ut lacus condimentum pellentesque id ut urna. Class aptent taciti 
sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. 
Praesent rhoncus vulputate leo at rutrum. Maecenas bibendum massa nec risus 
elementum volutpat. Duis dolor mi, facilisis ut accumsan consequat, fermentum 
vel orci. Nam sagittis, elit et hendrerit pellentesque, sem sapien interdum 
nunc, a convallis turpis erat nec turpis. Integer sed tortor tellus, id mollis 
diam. Nullam a turpis eu lorem sagittis congue nec vitae ligula. Integer tempus 
varius iaculis.

    Fusce nec augue sit amet ante hendrerit convallis eu ac enim. Aliquam in 
justo id erat hendrerit porta semper a ante. Mauris a elementum tellus. Proin 
facilisis lacus a nunc semper malesuada. Duis quis augue est, ut posuere 
turpis. Nam lobortis dui vel odio dignissim ultricies. Curabitur sapien urna, 
ornare non pulvinar sed, vehicula at sapien. Sed velit sapien, tincidunt in 
eleifend ut, malesuada feugiat nulla. Quisque in sapien non odio blandit 
porttitor id id mi. 
    \item 

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum eu 
ligula ut lacus condimentum pellentesque id ut urna. Class aptent taciti 
sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. 
Praesent rhoncus vulputate leo at rutrum. Maecenas bibendum massa nec risus 
elementum volutpat. Duis dolor mi, facilisis ut accumsan consequat, fermentum 
vel orci. Nam sagittis, elit et hendrerit pellentesque, sem sapien interdum 
nunc, a convallis turpis erat nec turpis. Integer sed tortor tellus, id mollis 
diam. Nullam a turpis eu lorem sagittis congue nec vitae ligula. Integer tempus 
varius iaculis.

    Fusce nec augue sit amet ante hendrerit convallis eu ac enim. Aliquam in 
justo id erat hendrerit porta semper a ante. Mauris a elementum tellus. Proin 
facilisis lacus a nunc semper malesuada. Duis quis augue est, ut posuere 
turpis. Nam lobortis dui vel odio dignissim ultricies. Curabitur sapien urna, 
ornare non pulvinar sed, vehicula at sapien. Sed velit sapien, tincidunt in 
eleifend ut, malesuada feugiat nulla. Quisque in sapien non odio blandit 
porttitor id id mi. 

    \end{enumerate}
    \end{document}
```

[image: Resulting output]

I want the first paragraph in each item to also be indented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I think this is what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
   [listparindent=\parindent,itemindent=\parindent,labelsep*=.5\parindent,parsep=0pt]
\item \kant[1-2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: The image you posted looks to be exactly what I want, but I'm getting an error: Package keyval Error: labelsep* undefined.

Comment: You probably have an older version of `enumitem` installed. Mine is `enumitem.sty 2011/09/28 v3.5.2` (Tex Live 2012).

Comment: Ahh yes mine is from 2009. Updating it now. I'll check back when the update finishes.