# indenting under item

Tags: indentation, itemize

I'm trying to indent paragraphs after doing `\item`, for instance

```
\item {\bf Research Question} \\
\indent The purpose of this research is
```

However, \indent is not working when I'm using \item. Would there be a way to solve this?

Comment: See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're better off using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to manage your lists:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \textbf{Something}

  Something else
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[listparindent=\parindent]
  \item \textbf{Something}

  Something else
\end{itemize}

\noindent \textbf{Something}

Something else

\end{document}
```

The `listparindent` key sets the `par`agraph `indent` inside a `list` item, where the default is `0pt`. Note that you have to insert an explicit `\par` or an empty line. It's better than using `\\` directly.

If you also want to indent the first paragraph in the `itemize`, then use `itemindent`, as suggested in [Indenting First Paragraph in a List](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98550/5764).